# Reaktor 6 vs 5 Learning differences

Tags: sound, daw, live-sound, audio, reaktor

If one searches for reaktor tutorials on youtube or elsewhere, he finds that there are many tutorials for reaktor 5 but not many for 6. I wanted to know if I can safely learn to make instruments(ensembles) by learning any of the reaktor 5 tutorials. Has making an ensemble changed from reaktor 5 to 6. Specifically has the core of the environment changed, like the signal flows and others or we can safely learn all of that and use that knowledge to make ensembles in reaktor 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Reaktor expert but I took a course a while ago. The teacher worked with Reaktor 6, I had Reaktor 5 installed.

My impression was that the new version offers some features and handy modules which did not exist in the former version. I could totally keep up with the class, just sometimes I had to find workarounds.

As your situation is the opposite, you should be fine with Reaktor 5 tutorials. To get an idea what has changed, I suggest taking a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KgzxcmCNUg) or [here](http://cdm.link/2015/09/heres-visual-tour-whats-new-reaktor-6/).

Have fun with this powerful piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use everything from 5 in 6. The real difference is that in 6 you have "blocks" which are special high level nodes that imitate modular synths and tools, and you can build setups much easier on the high level. In find them amazing, one of the best features.